# pure-ftpd not support STOR \ format

Tags: acronis, ftp

im using Pure-ftpd with Acronis true image server

but when i create a Vault acronis try to make a ID file on the ftp server

but using raw ftp command STOR \ID

and im get this error from ftp

553 Prohibited file name: \

ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

How about: `STOR /ID`

(It's about unix pathnames)